# Aligning words with different widths

Tags: html, css

I know this sounds like a silly question, but I'm having a brain fart and cannot think of an easy solution. I just keep thinking of tables, and I really don't want to go that route.

I have a list of people that have a wait time next to them. I now have to stick their 'status' next to the person. This is no issue, however I'm being ocd and the fact that the status's don't quite line up bugs me greatly.

I've included a snippit of what I'm trying to do. I have tried floating and a few other tricks, but I just can't seem to get them even.

The one thing I cannot do is change the html. I have it this way so I can insert blocks of html and I cannot refactor that code.

```css
.waitlist {
  width: 40%;
}

.waitlist .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid light-gray;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .4em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .4em;
}

.waitlist .panel-body h4 {
  line-height: .5em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .4em 0;
}

.waitlist .order {
  padding-left: .5em;
}

.waitlist .EstWaitTime {
  float: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="waitlist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);">
      <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-size: 1.25em;">
<span>Wait time:</span>
<span class="pull-right">4 hr 0 min</span>

</h3>
    </div>
    <p class="clearfix"></p>
    <div class="panel-body clearfix">

      <!-- ko foreach: WaitList -->

      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order" >1.</span>
<span class="name">tes, e</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">Next</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>

      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">2.</span>
<span class="name">fdg, 3</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">25 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">3.</span>
<span class="name">fdg, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">50 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">4.</span>
<span class="name">gdf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 5 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">5.</span>
<span class="name">dsf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 30 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">6.</span>
<span class="name">gf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 55 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">7.</span>
<span class="name">thi, d</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">2 hr 20 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">8.</span>
<span class="name">fds, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">2 hr 45 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">9.</span>
<span class="name">rtr, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">3 hr 10 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">10.</span>
<span class="name">tss, g</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">3 hr 35 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>
      <!-- /ko -->

    </div>
    <div class="disclamier panel-footer" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
      <p>Wait times are approximate. Actual wait time may vary.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .So what should this look like?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with using tables-- this seems like tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give each of the preceding elements a fixed width, though I don't know what's wrong with using tables; this seems like tabular data.

Specifically:

```
.order {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
}
```

---

```css
.waitlist {
  width: 40%;
}
.waitlist .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid light-gray;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .4em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .4em;
}
.waitlist .panel-body h4 {
  line-height: .5em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .4em 0;
}
.waitlist .order {
  padding-left: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.waitlist .EstWaitTime {
  float: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
.waitlist .name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="waitlist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);">
      <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-size: 1.25em;">
<span>Wait time:</span>
<span class="pull-right">4 hr 0 min</span>

</h3>
    </div>
    <p class="clearfix"></p>
    <div class="panel-body clearfix">

      <!-- ko foreach: WaitList -->

      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order" >1.</span>
<span class="name">tes, e</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">Next</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>

      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">2.</span>
<span class="name">fdg, 3</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">25 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">3.</span>
<span class="name">fdg, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">50 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">4.</span>
<span class="name">gdf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 5 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">5.</span>
<span class="name">dsf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 30 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">6.</span>
<span class="name">gf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 55 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">7.</span>
<span class="name">thi, d</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">2 hr 20 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">8.</span>
<span class="name">fds, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">2 hr 45 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">9.</span>
<span class="name">rtr, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">3 hr 10 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>


      <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif; display: block;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">10.</span>
<span class="name">tss, g</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">3 hr 35 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>
      <!-- /ko -->

    </div>
    <div class="disclamier panel-footer" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
      <p>Wait times are approximate. Actual wait time may vary.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I knew I was overthinking this! I always do that! :)

Comment: @zazvorniki You're welcome! Just make sure that the width you set won't overflow, or make sure you're prepared for one. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tables would seem to be the answer.

```css
.panel-body {
  display: table;
  width: 400px
}
.people {
  display: table-row;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.people span {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.EstWaitTime {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body clearfix">
  <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
<span class="order">6.</span>
<span class="name">gf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 55 min</span>
</h4>
  <h4 class="people" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
<!--<p  class='pull-left'>-->
<span class="order">5.</span>
<span class="name">dsf, f</span>
<span style="font-size:.6em;color:#4f851b;" class="status">Arrived</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='pull-right'>-->
<span class="EstWaitTime">1 hr 30 min</span>
<!--</p>-->
<!--<p class='clearfix'></p>-->
</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't be afraid of tables for tabular data!

Yes, they are bad for laying out pages, but from your description you have inherently tabular data that needs to be displayed in a tabular layout. That's exactly what tables are for, so don't feel afraid to use them.

[It's OK to Use Tables](http://adrianroselli.com/2012/07/its-ok-to-use-tables.html)

Comment: It's because I would have to restructure the entire html and if I do that then I have to modify 3000 line of javascript. Also, this is being displayed on a kiosk and this model does not play well with tables

Comment: Fair enough. "Technical constraint" is something we all have to deal with. It's surprising that a kiosk would play poorly with tables but work perfectly fine using more advanced CSS layouts.